# How do you get the full size url of an attachment image

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments, images

I do not see a way to get the URL to the full sized image of an attachment.

Yes, i can use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full')`, but that is of no help if the image is not the featured image.

[wp_get_attachment_metadata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) on my attachment does not show a **full** size, so therefore [wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID, 'full')](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) returns nothing.

How do I get the full version of an image given the attachment ID?

Comment: There is no `full` in `sizes`, the original is under the key `file` in the data returned from `wp_get_attachment_metadata`. Regardless, `wp_get_attachment_image_src($imageID, 'full')` is correct, and will return an array containing the URL.

Comment: I thought I tested `wp_get_attachment_image_url($imageID, 'full')` before posting. You are right, to my surprise. I'm not sure why I thought it was failing

Answer (score 5):

I solved this using `wp_get_attachment_url($imageID);`

But, you can also use `wp_get_attachment_image_url($imageID, 'full')`

Comment: Jeff that's exactly what i answered you in part 2 of my answer...

Comment: I wasn't asking about post thumbnails. I was specifically asking about attachments not directly tied to a post. feel free to adjust your answer accordingly.... and i realized I made a mistake when testing wp_get_attachment_image_url() only after @milo pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're overthinking the system.  Unfortunately the nomenclature isn't helping.  The Thumbnail here is the actual image when you use get_the_post_thumbnail_url().

as an example.  Say today you uploaded an image called myimage.jpg.

That would go, if you're storing images by date into this directory:
/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/myimage.jpg.

Now when you call :

```
$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full');  //(or leave the parameter blank)

echo $featured_img_url;
```

you would get:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/myimage.jpg
```

On the other hand if you used this code:

```
$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail');  //(or choose a different thumbnail size..medium...large...)

echo $featured_img_url;
```

it would return:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/myimage30x30.jpg
```

the autogenerated image based on your thumbnail settings.

to avoid the naming confusion you could also try...

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_url()
```

but this requires the actual attachment id, not post id, whether or not you're in the loop.

```
$imgid = 6; //need to get it dynamically
$imgurldesktop = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $imgid, '' ); //use default image size
$imgurlmobile = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $imgid, 'home-slide-img-mobile' ); //use custom set size
```

Comment: I am talking about images uploaded via Advanced Custom Fields, and not directly tied to a post. Thats why i'm messing with wp_get_attachment_image_url(), because i know the attachment ID.